# python splitting string twice

Tags: python, string, split

I'm trying to split a string twice with the goal of converting a>b where b contains numbers and is split into multiple x/y pairs

```
a = '{1;5}{2;7}{3;9}{4;8}'
b = [[1,5],[2,7],[3,9],[4,8]]
```

my code is currently this...

```
b = a.split('}{')
for item in b:
    item.replace('{','')
    item.replace('}','')
    item.split(';')
```

the first split works correctly and returns this

```
b = ['{1;5','2;7','3;9','4;8}']
```

but manipulating the 'items in b' does not appear to work

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to do both splits at once and return a list of lists:

```
>>> a = '{1;5}{2;7}{3;9}{4;8}'
>>> [item.split(';') for item in a[1:-1].split('}{')]
[['1', '5'], ['2', '7'], ['3', '9'], ['4', '8']]
```

Comment: `map` is deprecated for that use (in favor of list comprehensions). You found just add an other one: `[[int(subitem) for subitem in item.split(';')] for item in a[1:-1].split('}{')]`

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually modify the list b by interacting with its item. You should do something like this:

```
for i, s in enumerate(b):
    b[i] = s.replace('{','')
    b[i] = s.replace('}','')
    b[i] = s.split(';')

In [9]: b
Out[9]: [['{1', '5'], ['2', '7'], ['3', '9'], ['4', '8}']]
```

I dont know if that's your expected output

Here are two examples where you are not affecting the list b

```
for item in b:
    item = item.replace('{','')
    item = item.replace('}','')
    item = item.split(';')

In [21]: b = ['{1;5','2;7','3;9','4;8}']

In [22]: for item in b:
        item = item.replace('{','')
        item = item.replace('}','')
        item = item.split(';')


In [23]: b
Out[23]: ['{1;5', '2;7', '3;9', '4;8}']
```

This one wouldnt do anything to the list b neither.

```
for item in b:
    item.replace('{','')
    item.replace('}','')
    item.split(';')
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

The items you are looking for inside the input string consist of

- two numbers `\d+`
- separated by a semicolon `;`
- enclosed in curly braces `\{`, `\}`.

The complete pattern looks like this:

```
pattern = r'\{(\d+);(\d+)\}'
```

The additional parentheses `()` define *groups* which allow extracting the numbers, for example with [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> for item in re.findall(pattern, a):
>>>     print item
('1', '5')
('2', '7')
('3', '9')
('4', '8')
```

Then it is a simple matter of mapping `int` over the items to get the desired result:

```
>>> [map(int, item) for item in re.findall(pattern, a)]
[[1, 5], [2, 7], [3, 9], [4, 8]]
```

Some prefer list comprehensions over `map`:

```
>>> [[int(x) for x in item] for item in re.findall(pattern, a)]
[[1, 5], [2, 7], [3, 9], [4, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The function call

```
item.replace('{','')
```

does not do anything to `item`, since it returns a new string after the replacement. Instead, try:

```
item = item.replace('{','')
```

Similar changes need to be made for the other lines in that block.

Comment: That's not what he wants, that will modify the item element but not the list b

Comment: The question is pretty unclear on what the OP actually *wants*. I identified an obvious error in the existing code. Of course further work will need to be done to actually do something with the result.

Comment: I think is really clear, he wants this output b = [[1,5],[2,7],[3,9],[4,8]] with this input a = '{1;5}{2;7}{3;9}{4;8}'. He does a split to b and receive this output b = ['{1;5','2;7','3;9','4;8}'] but fails modifying b through editing it's item in the loop.

Comment: Great. Perhaps you can write an answer which does all the work for him.